# Dropzonejs issues - Dragleave not working as expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropzone.js

I am working on [Dropzonejs](http://dropzonejs.com) for multiple file upload with drag and drop option enabled.

I am facing the following issues.

1. I have implemented **dragenter** successfully to detect drag into the dropzone and show a different preview div(.dz-drag). Upon drag leave, the default preview should be shown again. Without dragleave function defined, the dragenter function is working fine.
2. As for drag leave, the plugin is not responding as desired. It appears as though drag leave is overriding dragenter function.

Here's my code

HTML

```
<div id="preview" class="dropzone">
   <div class="dz-drag">
       <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
       <p>Drop files here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>           
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {// Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: "insert-status.php", // Set the url
        method: 'POST',
        paramName: 'image',
        parallelUploads: 1,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        thumbnailWidth: 80,
        thumbnailHeight: 80,
        autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        dictResponseError: "Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again.",
        previewsContainer: "#preview", // Define the container to display the previews
        clickable: ".file-click, #preview", //Define all the Clickable elements for this Dropzone
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png, image/bmp, video/mp4, video/avi, video/mvi, video/3gp",

        dragenter: function(file) {
            $('.dz-preview').hide();
            $('.dz-drag').show();
            $('.preview-cont').addClass('added'); //Show Preview Container
        },
        dragleave: function(file) {
            alert('leave');
            $('.dz-drag').hide();
            $('.dz-preview').show();
            $('.preview-cont').removeClass('added'); //Show Preview Container
            $('.preview-cont').removeClass('added'); //Hide Preview Container - Not working
        },
        drop: function(file) {
            $('.dz-preview').show();
            $('.dz-drag').hide();
        }
```

CSS

```
   .preview-cont:not(.added){
display:none;
}

.dz-preview.default{
    width: 80px;
    margin:5px 3px;
    border: 0.17em dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
}
.dz-preview.default .glyphicon{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:35%;
    margin-left:40%;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:150%;
}

.dz-preview.default:hover{
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
.dz-preview.default:hover > .glyphicon{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.dz-drag{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-align:center;
    border:2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

3. Also, there is a need in my requirement to know whether there is a file already present in my dropzone, be it in ADDED, QUEUED, UPLOADING or any other file status. Is there a way by which I can detect the file presence, other than using the built in getFilesWithStatus function? My intention is to detect with a single function call.
4. I have handled maxfilesreached function by disabling/hiding clickable links and buttons. Now, when the last added file is removed, I want to re-enable all the disabled links. I have not found a way to perform this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try dragover and dragleave
2. See 1.
3. Not sure what you mean by "detected file presence", but does the drop event help?
4. I've used removedfile event, and I just count how many preview templates are on the page. If 0, last  file was removed.